# Do these aarch64 intrinsics have alignment requirements?

Tags: rust, arm64, neon

Do the [`core::arch::aarch64`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/aarch64/index.html) functions [`vld1q_u8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/aarch64/fn.vld1q_u8.html) and [`vst1q_u8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/core/arch/aarch64/fn.vst1q_u8.html) have any alignment requirements? The documentation doesn't mention any, but the documentation is also very sparse, so I'm wondering if there is one that's just not documented. I'm not sure how to figure out from the ARM documentation whether any such requirement exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vld1q_xxx` / `vst1q_xxx` are wrappers around SIMD `vld1`/`vst1` instructions.

For details look armv8 documentation [vld1](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0597/2020-12/SIMD-FP-Instructions/VLD1--multiple-single-elements---Load-multiple-single-1-element-structures-to-one--two--three--or-four-registers-?lang=en)

But shortly, address should be aligned to element size, in your case of reading bytes, it's 1 byte.
In case of 16b data, 2 bytes, etc

So rule of thumb follow element size alignment.

As a side note, `vld`/`vst` support unaligned access, but it might be disabled by system. Refer `SCTLR` register for that.

Comment: With the added footnote that although alignment isn't required, it can still help performance (reduces number of accesses spanning multiple cache lines).